# Do I need to use await with both Add and SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have code like this now:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(PageVM page)
{
...
    await _context.AddAsync(dto);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I am wondering if I should use `await` and `async` methods with both `Add` and `SaveChanges` or is using it just in one place enough?

Comment: Do you know why you use async/await at all?

Comment: `await` means: *do this and do not proceed further until this is done. I (the calling) am going to leave and do something else (or not). Let me know once it is done.* Now that you know what it means, do you need them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `SaveChanges` method execute all changes in internal tree of EF, sending querys asynchronously in separates transactions and return to entitys any changues of BBDD by default (autonumerics, triggers, etc ...). 
The `Add` method only add in internal tree of EF that entity (or dto) has been "added".

Logically it should only be used `SaveChangues` for async. For `Add` need more time for create task and you will not optimize times ... Always create async methods for all, it's not a good way ....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you only have access to async methods, you should wait for them. If you have access to the synchronous calls, you may consider what D3ivid said in his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50891291/8805908.

Consider that if you chose not to wait for any of the methods, you cannot be sure that the item is added before the event has been raised. You may even start further tasks when you return from this method, which assumes that the item already has been added and the event has been raised.